# Error occurs when compiling OptiX SDK 3.9 with CMake

Tags: visual-studio, cuda, cmake, optix

I'm using Win10-x64.
I install Visual Studio 2010, CUDA 7.5, OptiX SDK 3.9.0 and CMake 3.5 in order.

Then I follow the INSTALL-WIN.txt in OptiX/SDK/ and try to compile the samples. I press configure, then:

```
CMake Error at CMake/FindOptiX.cmake:75 (message):
  optix library not found.  Please locate before proceeding.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMake/FindOptiX.cmake:84 (OptiX_report_error)
  CMakeLists.txt:189 (find_package)
```

Then I copy `/../lib64/*` to `/../lib/*` and `/../bin64/*` to `/../bin/*`

Error above seem to be fixed but new ERROR:

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
CUDA_cufft_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)
    linked by target "ocean" in directory C:/ProgramData/NVIDIA Corporation/OptiX SDK 3.9.0/SDK/ocean
```

I try CMake3.0 and get the same result.

Comment: Sorry for bothering. Using "Visual Studio 12 2010 Win64" can fix all this problem. 32-bit support is removed in OpiX 3.9.

Comment: Since you've figured out how to fix the issue, why not provide an answer to your own question (yes, you can do that) explaining what you did?  That will make it most useful for future readers.  Later on, you can come back and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three month ago, OptiX 3.9 was released. ALL 32-bit support has been removed.
If you compile the file with 32-bit compiler, CMake will report this error.

The INSTALL-WIN.txt document in the \SDK directory is updated, and it reminds user to compile with 64-bit compiler. Just choose the compiler with the "win64" suffix.

[win64 compiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwvwC.png)